# Is a question about whether something is possible on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Is a question that asks whether something is possible within the laws of physics on-topic here?

(Very vague) Example: assuming any level of technology, can you do this within the laws of physics, or would some law(s) of physics prevent it?

Would such a question be on-topic here (with more details of course)?

Answer (score 3):

If the question is about physics, then the content of that question does not determine if it is on topic or off topic. "Is is possible" physics questions can be on topic or off topic depending on what the goal is.

If the question is asking in order to further a personal theory or design a product (engineering), then I would say it is not for PSE.

If the question is asking if something is possible in the context of trying to better understand a specific physics concept, then I would say it is on topic for PSE.$^*$

---

$^*$ Of course, the question also needs to follow other site policies, be understandable, be focused, etc.